# Materializecss Sidenav freezes

Tags: css, materialize

I have been struggling a lot lately with this problem and I have not been able to debug the root cause of the problem. At first when I installed materializecss on my website it worked absoulutely fine but when I designed the `<nav>` with my custom CSS then it stopped working properly.

This is full screen view of the page,

[image]

---

This is mobile or tablet view,

[image]

---

And this is where the problem starts, as soon as I click on that list button the screen freezes till I click again. Here's the view of that,

[image]

---

Waiting for a quick response. If you need any other info, just ask :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you load

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

at least in your init.js?